# Substring in linq

Tags: c#, linq

My data is as below on which I want to run a `linq` query

```
MyTable
ID        DATA
1         1:40:567
```

my query is

```
var query = (from tab in MyTable
             where tab.DATA.Substring(0, tab.DATA.IndexOf(":")) == "1"))
             select new
             {
                tab.ID,
                tab.DATA
             }).ToList();
```

I get an error

> InnerException    {"Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."}  System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}

I want the substring of the data column. Please help

Comment: can you provide generated sql query?

Comment: It wouldn't be better to match a REGEX?, the problem with substrings is that if the string is null or empty a substring will result in an exceptions if it's not handled correctly

Comment: is data a Date Type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var query = (from tab in MyTable
             where tab.DATA.TrimStart(new [] {' ', '0', '\t'}).StartsWith("1")
             select new
             {
                tab.ID,
                tab.DATA
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: Please explain. Does this mean that if my value is 22 it wont work?

Comment: Don't understand. 22 of what? Is it time in `DATA` and its format always '0:00:00', right? The code should work

Comment: Yes that works. But I don't really understand why. Why is there no delimiter used? I had to remove TrimStart due to an error though

Comment: @JackGray It will also accept '10:` which your original code wouldn't.  Basically anything that starts with `1` regardless of where the colon is.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have one single `char` to verify, try to use the `substring` to get one char, for sample:

```
var data= (from tab in MyTable
             where tab.DATA.Substring(0, 1) == "1")
             select new
             {
                tab.ID,
                tab.DATA
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: No I may not have just one char. Its data in a table and finally the index would increase

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var dataStartsWith = 1; // or another number

var query = (from tab in MyTable
         where tab.DATA.StartsWith(dataStartsWith + ":")
         select new
         {
            tab.ID,
            tab.DATA
         }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will match any record that starts with `1:`.  If that is what you really want then you can just do:

```
var query = (from tab in MyTable
             where tab.DATA.StartsWith("1:")
             ...
```

This has the added benefit of being able to take advantage of an index on `DATA` if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var query = (from tab in MyTable
         where tab.DATA.Split(':')[0] == "1"))
         select new
         {
            tab.ID,
            tab.DATA
         }).ToList();
```